# Why is getFirstVisiblePosition right when rotating to horizontal, but wrong when rotating back?

Tags: android, listview, lifecycle

I have an Android ListView. I want the visible portion of the list to stay (roughly) the same when the user turns the device. So I save the first visible position on destruction of the activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    this.currentPosition = this.listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState, productFilter = " + this.productFilter + "; currentPosition = " + this.currentPosition);
    outState.putInt("productFilter", this.productFilter);
    outState.putInt("currentPosition", this.currentPosition);
}
```

(Please ignore the productFilter, it's not related to this question.) And I restore it in onCreate like this:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.productFilter = savedInstanceState.getInt("productFilter");
        this.currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPosition");
        Log.i(TAG, "productFilter = " + this.productFilter + "; currentPosition = " + this.currentPosition);
    }
```

When rotating the emulator from vertical to horizontal, this works nicely. When rotating it back to vertical, the `getFirstVisiblePosition()` in the save method always returns zero, although the actually visible item has been far away. This is the output of the logs:

```
03-12 19:16:36.140: INFO/WindowManager(51): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=de_DE touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3 orien=2 layout=34}
03-12 19:16:36.180: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): onSaveInstanceState, productFilter = 0; currentPosition = 53
03-12 19:16:36.190: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): onCreate
03-12 19:16:36.190: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): productFilter = 0; currentPosition = 53
03-12 19:16:36.220: INFO/WindowManager(51): onOrientationChanged, rotation changed to 0
03-12 19:16:36.220: INFO/WindowManager(51): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
03-12 19:16:36.241: INFO/WindowManager(51): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=de_DE touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3 orien=1 layout=34}
03-12 19:16:36.270: DEBUG/StatusBar(51): updateResources
03-12 19:16:36.340: DEBUG/StatusBar(51): updateResources
03-12 19:16:36.610: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): onSaveInstanceState, productFilter = 0; currentPosition = 0
03-12 19:16:36.620: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): onCreate
03-12 19:16:36.620: INFO/ExperimentalList(777): productFilter = 0; currentPosition = 0
```

Is there any reason why the first time the position was correctly yielded at 53, but the second time as zero? I can't prove it by the logs here, but I swear I tried this a few times and I never scrolled back to zero!

Comment: Does it work if you scroll it manually a bit before changing it back? Maybe it doesn't update the visible position after programmatically scrolling to the original position.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setSelection. After

```
this.currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPosition");
```

add

```
this.listView.setSelection(this.currentPosition);
```

*caveat: this will change your selected item.